# Is the global sections functor exact for a SES of O_X-modules on an affine scheme when the middle is quasicoherent?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-schemes, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $X$ be an affine scheme.  Suppose we have an exact sequence of $\mathcal{O}_{X}$-modules
\begin{equation*}
0 \to \mathcal{F}_{1} \xrightarrow{\phi} \mathcal{F}_{2} \xrightarrow{\psi} \mathcal{F}_{3} \to 0.
\end{equation*}
If $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ is quasi-coherent, does this imply that the sequence of global sections
\begin{equation*}
0 \to \mathcal{F}_{1}(X) \xrightarrow{\phi(X)} \mathcal{F}_{2}(X) \xrightarrow{\psi(X)} \mathcal{F}_{3}(X) \to 0
\end{equation*}
is also exact?

If we assume that $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ is quasi-coherent, the answer is yes.  This is proved in Hartshorne, Proposition II.5.6.  In the proof, the quasi-coherence of $\mathcal{F}_{1}$ is used to show that for a distinguished open affine $D_{f}$ of $X$ and a section $s \in \mathcal{F}_{2}(D_{f})$ there is some positive integer $N$ such that $f^{N}s$ is the restriction of a global section of $\mathcal{F}_{2}$.  However, the quasi-coherence of $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ should allow us to conclude this lifting property directly.  With this change the argument seems to go through without assuming the quasi-coherence of $\mathcal{F}_{1}$.

I can't see any mistakes in the argument.  But I also don't have a good reason why the quasi-coherence of $\mathcal{F}_{2}$ should force $H^{1}(X,\mathcal{F}_{1})$ to vanish.  Thanks!

Comment: Just a thought: Let $U$ and $V$ be disjoint nontrivial opens of $X$, and write $i$ and $j$ for their open immersions. Take $\mathcal{F}_3$ to be $i_! \mathcal{O}_U \oplus j_! \mathcal{O}_V$. Let $\mathcal{F}_2$ be $\mathcal{O}_X$, and let $\mathcal{F}_1$ be the kernel of the natural map $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{F}_3$. The map $\mathcal{O}_X \to \mathcal{F}_3$ is surjective on stalks, but not on global sections. If someone can tell me that I'm not making a mistake I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: @JeroenvanderMeer I don't think there is any non trivial map $\mathcal{O}_X\to j_!\mathcal{O}_U$ for a (non closed) open $U$. However, you can come up with a counter-example the other way around, that is with a map $0\to j_!j^{-1}\mathcal{O}_X\to \mathcal{O}_X$

Comment: Right! Thanks for the correction, something indeed felt fishy with my idea...

Comment: You are right, the extension by zero exact sequence gives a counterexample.  I understand Hartshorne's argument better now.  Thanks!